# Gun game is missing on PS4

Tags: ps4, call-of-duty-ghosts

I’ve played COD:Ghosts the other day on a PS3 and really like playing gun game. So to start with I brought COD:WW2 but to my disappointment there was no gun game. Today I brought COD:Ghosts but again I’m missing the gun game. Am I doing something wrong or how can I play gun game on my PS4?

Answer (score 3):

Okay I found the reason. To be able to play gun game offline I had to play it online first, I never checked there only online where the game was not to be found in the lists